# How to enable drag and drop functionality in jetpack compose lazy column/row

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In recycler view we can implement drag and drop functionality using ItemTouchHelper. How can i achieve the same thing in jetpack compose lazy column/row

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items

@Composable
fun MessageList(messages: List<Message>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(messages) { message ->
            MessageRow(message)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently made an example app with drag and drop `LazyColumn`.

You have the example here : https://github.com/VincentVInsideApp/compose-drag-drop-list

This solution permits :

Drag-and-Drop Reordering: Users can reorder items in the list by simply dragging and dropping them to their desired position.

Smooth Animations: The composable provides smooth animations for item transitions during drag-and-drop operations.

Customization: You can customize the appearance of each item by providing your own itemComposable

Answer (score -2):

Use Modifiers. Modifier.pointerInput() can be used to react to gestures. See the official docs on Animation in Compose. It shows an example implementing a swipe to dismiss (delete) a list item. Hopefully you can implement something custom to achieve your desired effect

Comment: the question is not about swipe to dismiss or touch events, it is much more complex without itemTouch Helper or something. If you find any useful code please mention that also